# Spherical Aberration Of Electron Lenses

Tags: optics, electrons, lenses, microscopy

I would like to know why electron lenses can't have negative spherical aberration. Every textbook I have found devotes one or two sentences to saying that Otto Scherzer prooved this 80 years ago, but no one actually explains why.

Comment: Allegedly the proof is in Scherzer O. 1936 Über einige Fehler von Elektronenlinsen. Z. Physik 101, 593–603. (doi:10.1007/BF01349606)

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I can't find a version of that paper that doesn't cost 40 euros.